# custom trap signal in ksh

Tags: signals, ksh, shell-trap

Is there a way for me to implement custom fake signals in ksh? Currently am capturing the ERR signal and exiting. However, due to a change, there are calls that may not return success, however that is a valid condition. In such case, I want to make sure that this call generates a different signal or handle the ERR differently. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kill` to send any signal you want to the current shell. You can use `exit` in a subshell or `return` in a function to set any error code you want.

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
trap 'echo USR1 signal processed' USR1
trap 'echo ERR signal processed' ERR
[[ $1 == a ]] && kill -s USR1 $$ || (exit 1)
echo "done"
```

Example:

```
$ ./testsignal
ERR signal processed
done
$ ./testsignal a
USR1 signal processed
done
```

Comment: Hmm, HI Dennis, interestingly this isnt working. I only see the echo done above and dont see the USR1 being caught. In the above case, even ERR is not caught. However, when I added the following chmod 777 / where I dont have permissions, it printed 'ERR signal processed'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could simply wrap the statements whose exit codes you want to treat specially in a construction that would simply do what you want (employing "or" or "if not" constructions and analyzing the exit codes).

That seems to be a much cleaner programming style, doesn't it?

Comment: :) thats what I am doing right now! wanted to clean up further and based on what I have, trapping signals into a few functions seemed to be the cleanest way